AWS Amplify Gen2 NextJS Google OAuth, Change userpool domain name to custom domain
I have configured my Amplify app with my custom-purchased domain after following documentation.
Now I'm trying to point my app request URL to Google OAuth (userpool domain - oauthCognitoDomain ) to have my custom domain (auth.mydomain.com) instead of the default AWS domain ({userpool}.auth.{region}.amazoncognito.com). For this, I have successfully configured my custom domain (auth.mydomain.com) in the Cognito user-pool custom domain section and added the DNS records according to documentation.
However, when I redeploy the app, it still picks up the default domain when generating the oauthCognitoDomain parameter in amplify_outputs.json. Because of this, the OAuth request URL to the Google consent screen always ends up showing the AWS domain instead of my custom domain.
Does anyone know how to configure or update the Amplify backend code to change the generated oauthCognitoDomain parameter in amplify_outputs.json?


Amplify pull not working? That should overwrite the outputs file with the new changes
